# Referencing ServiceContract from other project

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, architecture

I've been searching all day, here and elsewhere, so please excuse any redundancy, but, I am trying to do what I gather is supposed to be simple, and the recommended way, of architecting a WCF service.

The scenario is one service, serving multiple ServiceContracts, each in it's own project.

I am starting simple; in my solution I have a WCF ServiceLibrary and a class library, and just a default config file.

I have another project in the solution called `WCF_Sandbox.Greeting`.  The assembly name is WCF_Sandbox.Greeting.dll

In that project is a class IGreeting (decorated as ServiceContract), and an implementing class Greeting.

I am **really** struggling to get the `SayHello()` method of `IGreeting` exposed via the `WCF_Sandbox` service.

I keep getting either the

> "this service is not listed in the services implemented by..."

error, or the error that

> no metadata is available.

If anyone could advise how to get services from this other project to appear in the WCF_Sandbox service, I would greatly appreciate it.  It seems this is a fundamental question a lot of people struggle with, and I haven't seen it answered in a straightforward way, anywhere.  Much thanks!

```
app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF_Sandbox.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF_Sandbox/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Sandbox.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Two things come to mind.  First, are you referencing the projects? Second, did you put the service model config (posted in your question) in the application hosting your service? Based on the comment at the top of the posted config, you're trying to use the config directly with the library.   Also, could you post how your projects are structured?  That might help us help you as well.

Comment: @Tim: The other project is referenced.  Putting the config in the app hosting the service?  Not yet. My solution has one WCF Service Library project, & one class library.  I want to define the servicecontract & implementing class in the class library, and have that served by the WCF service.  The WCF Test Client doesn't show the service from the class library, & either I get an error that metadata is not discoverable or I get an error that the service is not in the list implemented by the project. I didn't include the endpoint here in the code, that is what I am hoping SO can give me.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim mentioned, code may be useful.

I'd suggest following steps:

1). Ensure projects references (@Tim suggested) - I think you already did it

2). May be I am wrong, but if your service contract is IGreeting, then endpoint should contains IGreeting and not Service1, and look like

> ... endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
>   contract="WCF_Sandbox.**IGreeting**"

3). Ensure contract property has full qualified interface name (i.e full namespace + interface name).

4). Try to use WCF configuration tool (available from Visual studio tools-> menu) to manually select your contract, then review your config file.

Comment: @evgenyl- thanks.  I wanted to keep this simple for now, there is not a lot of code to post. As per above, I'd like a class library to define the interface/ServiceContract and implementing class, & have a separate service library serve the contract from that class. I've done #1 & #4, it may be that I am hung up on how to do #s 2&3 correctly.  That is why I left any required endpoint off.  I did try your example before posting, and it did not work, so I am not sure what I have wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish - you want to separate the service from other code via libraries - which is all well and good, but I think you have some basic misunderstandings.  I'm not sure what your overall level of experience is, so please forgive me if anything I say is something you already know or understand.

First, libraries are not executable code.  The only way to use a library (that I'm aware of) is to have an executing program consume it.  They provide a way to share code among multiple applications without having multiple copies of the source code.  In WCF terms, it's a way to separate the contracts from the hosting application.

So in your case, it sounds like you have already created the library (by the way, a WCF Service Library **is** a class library - it's just a different project template to get you up and running with WCF).

What you need to do next is host the service.  You can do this via IIS, a Windows Service or a self-hosted application.  For example, if you were going to host your service in IIS, you would put the library (DLL) containing your service in the bin folder of the virtual directory/application where you plan on hosting the service.  Then you will add a *.svc file for the service in the root of the virtual directory/application, and copy the ServiceModel section from the default app.config file to the web.config file.

To consume the service, you can either add a service reference through Visual Studio (in the project that will be consuming the service) or generate a proxy via SvcUtil and include it in the client project.

In short, if I understand your setup correctly, you're partway there.  You just need to host the service and then write a client to consume it.

There are a lot of things I haven't covered here - this is just one way to go about what I think you're trying to do.

I strongly suggest going through Microsoft's [Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) - particularly the parts about hosting and creating the client.

I hope this clears up some of your confusion - WCF is wonderful in its many different options and flavors, but it can also have a steep learning curve.